# curl usage wso2-am example api

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

just started with wso2-am.  I published the example PizzaShackAPI: /pizzashack/1.0.0 API and registered a default application against it. I can (re)generate keys for the default application and with this, I can call e.g. the GET/menu item in the API console. This gives me the expected list as long as the access token is valid.

However in the API console the equivalent curl command is also given as :

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer 00cb3832-f73f-3536-b287-4330a47ef4bd' 'https://192.168.1.9:8243/pizzashack/1.0.0/menu'
```

I run this under windows (curl-7.54.0-win64-mingw) but this doesn't work. Tried replacing some quotes with double quotes etc. but all to no avail. Furthermore, I assume that I am using one-way SSL to the service running in wso2-am itself (on port 8243) and I don't need to supply any certificate myself. I also realize that the server side uses a self signed certificate and not sure whether this has any implications in this situation.

Hope someone can help me out on this.

As an addition - just noticed that in the sys$output of the wso2-am server the following is listed:

```
[2017-05-13 00:38:38,858] ERROR - SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert:
 unknown_ca
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1639)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1607)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1776)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1068)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:890)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:764)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doUnwrap(SSLIOSession.ja
va:245)
```

I think that this is caused by the curl command hitting the API service .

Thanks Peter

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing HTTPS url of the API, You have to either use a keystore or suppress the SSL in cURL with -k option

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer 00cb3832-f73f-3536-b287-4330a47ef4bd' 'https://192.168.1.9:8243/pizzashack/1.0.0/menu' -k
```

You also can use below HTTP URL of the API, note the port difference.

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer 00cb3832-f73f-3536-b287-4330a47ef4bd' 'http://192.168.1.9:8280/pizzashack/1.0.0/menu'
```

Comment: Hi Abimaran,  thanks very much for the feedback.  I am going to try out your suggestion.  As I indicated earlier I have just started with ws02-am . So possibly this scenario is described further down the road but what does the keystore need to contain to be able to use SSL for this example API invocation outside of the ws02-am api console screen? (or perhaps you can supply a link to the documentation) ?  Thanks Peter